# How to test Spring mvc controller tests for response entity?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, gson

The controller is like:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/autocomplete")
    public ResponseEntity<String> autoComplete(@RequestParam("query") final String searchKey)
 {     
        List<String> list = ...     
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonString = gson.toJson(list);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(jsonString, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

I couldn't find a way to test the ResponseEntity using Spring mvc controller. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried the docs? https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In spring integration test framework, it provides class MockMvc to test controllers.

```
MockMvc mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build(); // was is a web application context.
MvcResult result = mvc
            .perform(
                    get("/autocomplete")
            .accept(
                    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();  // verify the response string.
```

Comment: I tried to test the controller this way, but i am getting the following error

Comment: `java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>
 at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:60)
 at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:89)
 at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$5.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:549)
 at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:141)
 `

Comment: Code 400 is client side error: A 400 means that the request was malformed. I noticed you put a request parameter in the controller's method, probably you have to change the request like `get("/autocomplete?query={query}", "{your search key}")`

Comment: My pleasure mate @mon123!